# ASCII encoding error when updating field content in SQL Server table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, ascii, unicode

I know there are plenty of posts and blog explanations about unicode errors, but I still can't figure out to handle it in my particular case. So here is my problem: I am writing a Python script to  update records in an SQL Server table, with field content from a shapefile that has been edited in ArcPad.

I use an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to update existing records.

I've put `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` on top of my script as I work with French characters.
Just doing so, I get the ASCII encoding error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

I've tried putting `u` before the field content:

```
...
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(DBtable, DBFields, where_clause) as DBCur:
    for DBrow in DBCur:
        ...
        DBrow[8] = u"{} - {}: {}".format(DBrow[8], date , AProw[8]) # AProw comes from a SearchCursor reading the shapefile.
```

I can then print a message with the text content, and it doesn't return an error message, but all characters are replaced (I get something like `???4???5????????>???5???` in my database field).

Any accentuated or punctuation character can be present in the fields (there's a free text comment field) so I don't want to check for every possible non-ASCII character and replace it.

I work with ArcGIS 10.2.2, the shapefile is edited in ArcPad 10.2 and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: This only occurs if the destination database is SQL Server. No problem with a file gdb.** I have to add that the SQL Server table already contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Would you be able to provide more details about your statement "When it's a new one, arcpy.da.InsertCursor doesn't work", please?  If arcpy.da.UpdateCursor is not causing encoding errors for you then my expectation is that arcpy.da.InsertCursor would not either and troubleshooting that rather than your arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute workaround might be the place to start instead.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a SQL Server database. Don't ask me why, I'm not a database expert and this is not the point anyway since I get errors with the UpdateCursor as well. ArcSDESQLExecute works also fine when there's no non ascii characters.

Comment: I'm not a database expert either - it's just that I've never had a problem with arcpy.da.InsertCursor and the way I read your question I thought you were saying "Update is OK, Insert causes problem".  The next thing I will suggest is that you may want to consider leaving arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute for a separate question and focus this one on your arcpy.da issue.  Or focus this one on arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute and leave arcpy.da to later - the main thing is to try and disentangle the two sets of symptoms.

Comment: Do you already know whether the same test would produce the same error if the data was stored in a file geodatabase *for testing purposes*?  I'm not proposing that you change where your data is stored, but not everyone has an ArcSDE for SQL Server instance on hand for testing so, if the error manifests in a file geodatabase too, then it opens your question up to a wider audience of potential answerers in advance of someone with SQL Server skills coming across it.

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not, but I just had to add encoding to my script, and I used the format `# coding=utf-8` on the **first line** of my script.

Comment: @Chad Cooper: I add -*- coding: cp1252 -*- in the beginning so my French characters are read fine. It's also usually enough, but apparently not when writing to a SQL Server database... With utf-8, my 'é' become 'Ã©', 'à' become 'Ã', etc in the print messages, and I get the same error message as above when writing to the database.

Comment: @GISGe Probably a stupid question by me, but are the target columns in SQL Server NVARCHAR rather than VARCHAR?

Comment: There are 2 text fields I tried to populate/update, one is NVARCHAR and the second one is TEXT. I had problems with both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution by bringing all of the following changes to my code:

- use `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute()` instead of `arcpy.da Insert/Update cursors` to update/populate the table (I had to do both operations and both types of cursors didn't really work in all situations).
- use `# -*- coding:utf8 -*-` in the beginning of the script, which is supposed to be a good practice anyway (`# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` allows me to have accents in the messages but doesn't work for editing the database table). Now accents in my messages are replaced, but editing my database works.
- there was also an issue with single quotes being recognized as string delimiters within my SQL request. To deal with this I had to replace them with *double* single quotes.

So now my code looks like this:

```
new_comment  = "{} - {}: {}".format(DBrow[8].replace("'", "''").encode('utf-8'), date , AProw[8]replace("'", "''").encode('utf-8')) 
# DBrow[8] is the comment already present in the table and AProw[8] is the new comment from my shapefile edited in ArcPad
...
sde_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(DB)  
sql = '''
update {} set {} = '{}'
'''.format(DBtable, DBcomment_field, new_comment)
```

Hope one day it might help anyone meeting this kind of unicode/SQL Server headache.